# Catch all DOM events on a page (without Firebug et. al.)

Tags: javascript, dom, cross-browser, dom-events

How would I go about creating a cross-browser script, that would intercept *all* events firing on
a page/browser window/DOM-tree (regardless of browser)?

What I'm hoping to accomplish is basically to get a better understanding of the different handling
of events in different browsers; I know the basic theory, but need to see to believe...

ADDED
I'm pretty well versed in both using frameworks, and working with "pure" Javascript.

What I want is sort of :

```
document.addEventListener('*', function(e){  
alert(e.type + ' is happening on ' + e.target), false);  
};
```

Comment: Not all events are supported by all browsers. Would you be looking for just the events that are common to all browsers? Only w3c defined events? Or are you partly interested in browser-specific events (eg `onpropertychange` in IE, `DOMAttrModified` in FF, etc)?

Comment: All events, my interest is mostly fueled by wanting to compare their handling(if not necessarily by the same means/events).

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that you can do to play around with is find out all events that exist and create a list of controls each with a different event and then label them accordingly and some alert boxes.

Then you can start firing the events and see how they are executing based on the alert boxes.

In future coding you could also use a JavaScript library that basically changes almost every existing JS code and functions so they they are all cross-browser.

Examples are(order of preference):

[MooTools](http://mootools.net/)

[JQuery](http://jquery.com/)

Not required but make life much simpler when it comes to cross-browser and creating fancy controls.

Comment: I personally prefer Mootools even tho JQuery is much more popular.